# ::Rails::Engine - No route found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I'm using ruby 2.4 and rails 5.

I'm trying to write my first gem and setup an engine to mount some basic controller logic.

I have the following as my engine:

```
Foo::Bar::Mylib::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :controller
end
```

My package structure is what I'm showing below and I have placed a dummy app in the spec folder.

```
mylib
  |- app
      |- controllers
          |- concerns
              |- foo
                  |- bar
                      |- mylib
                          |- controller.rb
  |- bin
      | *.*
  |- config
     |- locales
        |- *.yml
     |- routes.rb
  |- lib
      |- foo
          |- bar
              |- mylib
                  |- engine.rb
                  |- version.rb
              |- mylib.rb
  | spec
      |- contollers
          |- mycontroller_spec.rb
      |- dummy
      |- *.* (other helper and spec related files)
```

For the dummy app I have included my concern:

```
include Foo::Bar::Mylib::Controller
```

And I have mounted the engine in the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Foo::Bar::Mylib::Engine => '/my/route'
end
```

I seem to be having a logic gap somewhere with how Engines work because I can see where it's mounted:

```
controller_index GET    /controller(.:format)          controller#index
                 POST   /controller(.:format)          controller#create
  new_controller GET    /controller/new(.:format)      controller#new
 edit_controller GET    /controller/:id/edit(.:format) controller#edit
      controller GET    /controller/:id(.:format)      controller#show
                 PATCH  /controller/:id(.:format)      controller#update
                 PUT    /controller/:id(.:format)      controller#update
                 DELETE /controller/:id(.:format)      controller#destroy
```

But I only want to add a route for one controller action.  My rspecs are showing:

```
 Failure/Error: get '/my/route'

 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"/my/route", :controller=>"my/route"}
```

when my spec looks request like:

```
get '/my/route'
```

Anyone mind lending some guidance?